# Fetched Results Controller objectAtIndexPath without using TableView

Tags: nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a *Core Data* financial app that needs to accumulate sales quantities contained in the Trans Entity for each product and then update the totals into the appropriate attribute of the Product Entity.

I am able to achieve this by nesting a for (transArray) inside and tableView (product). 
However I need to sort and format the `tableView` based on the results first.

General Question: Can fetched results be used **without** tableViews?

```
- (void)calculateAmounts {
     NSIndexPath *indexPath=0;

    for (Product *product in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects){      // All product records
        selectedProduct = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // >>>>>NSLog shows correct number of object, however selectedProduct @ Index Path Are NULL

        for (id product1 in transProductArray)  {              // An array of all of the trans for product

            if ((NSNull *)product1 == [NSNull null]) {

            }
            else if ([product1 isEqualToString:selectedProduct]) {
                float qty = [@"1" floatValue];
                NSNumber *numQty=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:qty];   // Update quantity sold in product by 1
                NSNumber *quantity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([selectedProduct.quantitySold floatValue] + [numQty floatValue])];
                selectedProduct.quantitySold = quantity;
                [self.product.managedObjectContext save:nil];
            } 
        }    // Next Trans
    }        // Next Product
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. Not (clearly) knowing the implementation, I will bet it ***is*** possible to use fetched results outside a tableview. However, the Overview of NSFetchedResultsController documentation has this as the first line:

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results
>   returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a
>   UITableView object.
>
> While table views can be used in several ways, fetched results
>   controllers are primarily intended to assist you with a master list
>   view.

This infers that the two objects are linked for efficiency and ease of use. Plus, there are monitors under-the-hood to watch for changes, etc.

What you may be looking for is a 'plain-old' `NSFetchRequest`. [A tutorial.](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/01/19/core-data-queries-using-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not to sure whether you still require an answer to this however I had the same issue myself. I overcame as described in my own question on the subject.

[Display multiple core data entities objects in 1 Non-Table View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397509/display-multiple-core-data-entities-objects-in-1-view-controller/26417372#26417372)

I inserted a small tableview into my VC and set it to alpha and used the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to enable displaying details in labels.

This was the only way I could overcome it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.  Like a lot of things the answer was too easy!  It's about the fetch, not the tableview.  Just do a fetch into an array, then loop though the array to accumulate your values: Also useful for finding a specific object or output to a CSV.

```
NSError *error;
NSNumber *total=0;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
 entityForName:@"TransDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 for (TransDetail *trans in fetchedObjects) {

       total = total + trans.amount;
  }
```