# Display multiple core data entities objects in 1 Non-Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I am unsure of how to word the Title and I apologise in advance if it's been asked before. I haven't found the answer.

Is it possible to display two (or more) Core Data contents in a single view? As an example, if you have an entity called Parents and one called Children, Parents has a ONE-MANY relationship with Children, can I display in a detail View Controller the following:

Parent Name: Mum Dad

Children: Child 1 Child 2 Child 3

At present I can only seem to display one or the other in a single view unless I add embed a Table View into the VC, but this solution isn't really viable in every scenario.

The flow of events is simple:

Table View Controller displaying the Name of parents in the Parents CD entity. Tap a row and then go to the details VC. From there I want to display the names of the parents selected and any children that has been saved to them.

Can anyone answer this likely simple issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetched results controller is configured (presumably) to fetch Parent objects.  As you have found, you cannot ask it to provide details of the Child objects.  But Parent objects should have a property which references them.  If that property is named "children", then you can access the children of any given parent as follows:

```
NSSet *currentChildren = parent.children;
```

or

```
NSSet *currentChildren = [parent valueForKey:@"children"];
```

So, in your `prepareForSegue` method, if you set `detailsVC.selectedParent = selectedParent;` then within your detailsVC, you can access the children as `self.selectedParent.children`.  That will be an unordered set of Child objects, but you can enumerate them all using `for ( in )`.  For example:

```
for (Child *child in self.selectedParent.children) {
    NSLog(@"Child name is %@", child.childFirstName);
}
```

should log the first names of all the children of the selected parent.

Comment: Great it looks the part. I will give this a try and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Works as you said, also alphabeticalises the names by default. Thanks, get's the tick from me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a fetch request that concatenates parents and children and set the result as content array to an array controller. This serves then as your data source for your table view.

Comment: Do you have a code example at all that I could use in either a method or in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot for an answer to this question and have come up with zilch by way of doing this.

Trying to concatenate the Parent and Children entities in the Master VC and pass the details to the detail VC through the prepareForSegue was not working correctly:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]){

        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController * detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        Parent * selectParent= (Parent *) [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        Children * children = (Children *) [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        detailsVC.selectedParent = selectedParent;
        detailsVC.showChildren = children;

    }

}
```

Among several other variations of the prepareForSegue and the DetailVC, it was not working and throwing errors due to the reference in the fetchedResults being directly to Parents, despite any sub reference to the Children set.

Reading the NSFetchedResultsController documentation I came across this:

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a UITableView object.
>
> While table views can be used in several ways, fetched results controllers are primarily intended to assist you with a master list view.

This effectively states that the `fetchedResults` is for displaying data in a table view with an assumed outlook that any other view's will not be capable of correctly using `fetchedResults`.

To overcome this I have used a very small table view controller in an unused space in my Detail VC and set it's alpha to 0.0.

The method to display the details of the child class was performed in the method below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Children * childDetails = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.childNameLabel.text = childDetails.childFirstName;

    return cell;
}
```

This overcame my problem fine. I know it's cheating but it worked. I hope that my finding helps someone in the same situation.

If there is a better method, please answer and I will gladly give it a tick.